# Question about polynomial congruences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$x^3 \equiv x(mod$ $ 3)$ for all x, whereas obviously $x^3$ and $x$ are not algebraically congruent $(mod$ $ 3)$. What does it mean to be algebraically congruent?. In this case the two polynomials can be viewed as $x^3+0x^2+0x+0 \equiv 0x^3+0x^2+x+0$, so for example the coefficients for $x^3$ are 1 and 0 which are not congruent $(mod$ $ 3)$. Is that right?

Comment: If you're following a text, what does that text define as two polynomials being algebraically congruent?

Comment: two polynomials g and f are congruent if the coefficients of each power of x in g and f are congruent (mod m). The text never mentions the word "algebraically" in the definitions, so I infer that's the right definition.

Comment: TheMathNoob In your last comment, what the definition is gives exactly what you spelled out before the final "Is that right?" question. OH, I guess your issue is with the extra qualifier "algebraically"... hard to guess what text intends but I'd guess same as without it.

Comment: That's what I think it is.